# The true fear of Count Dracula

Tags: plot-explanation, dracula-2020

When Van Helsing explains what truly scares Count Dracula in the 2020 TV-series, she says it's something that explains all his "smaller" fears or restrictions:

- fear of the cross
- fear of the Sun
- sleeping on his origin land soil
- entering private property without an invitation

His biggest fear seems to be fear of death and that's why he keeps on sucking that girl's blood, because *"she seems to be not afraid of death"*

The thing is, I can accept that the cross represents the commitment of Jesus to die, the soil representing his eternal rest underground and the Sun that we believe it will kill him scares him...

But **how does this bigger fear explain why he can't enter without an invitation?**

---

> Note: as seen the Sun is not really harmful for him. It's part of the folklore that even he believed to the point of immense fear.

Could be similar with the invitation. Either way, that he absorbs the myths is not just the **one explanation** that Van Helsing wanted to find as one unique truth.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45052/where-did-the-idea-of-vampire-invitation-first-originate

Comment: @Paulie_D - That may explain it as an origin, but it doesn't address how the fear of death (as stated in the movie apparently) creates the entry barrier.

Comment: Basically there is no logical reason. It's just part of the mythology.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah I guess. But in the TV show she seems pretty confident about an answer that explains everything

Comment: If i remember correctly she stated that it is because no one wanted to have Dracula inside so he "created" that rule, that he must be invited. Something like "I only come if you really want me to be there"

Comment: I added a !spoiler tag because that info is only revealed at very the end of the last episode.

Comment: There is a joke that the only wooden frame you come through uninvited is the coffin.

Comment: @Luciano thank! although the fear of death as the greatest fear is also revealed at the end

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY nice one!

Comment: @lois6b Answer soon to come :)

Comment: @Charles _"soon"_ lol

Comment: @lois6b Sorry, I've been lazy with providing answers lately. Posting my answer now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how does this bigger fear explain why he can't enter without an invitation?

#### It doesn't necessarily. The inability for Dracula to enter a home uninvited is a superstition that he falsely believed in just like all the other superstitions.

Numerous times throughout the first season both Agatha and Dr. Zoe Van Helsing pick fun at Dracula for not being able to control his desires, for being a complete slave to immediate gratification/instincts (like a beast). First with Agatha's blood at the gates of the nunnery in S01E01, then with Dracula feeding on all the passengers so quickly in S01E02, and then again in S01E03 when Zoe and Dracula are at Dracula's penthouse talking about Lucy.

A beast [dog] enters a home only when invited, and if the beast attempts to enter unwelcomed then it's subject to being disciplined. The fears/superstitions that Dr. Zoe Van Helsing mentioned at the end of S01E03 were described as, "The Rules of the Beast", and for hundreds of years Dracula blindly followed them all. It was only after Dr. Zoe confronted him about it (by pulling the curtains down and showing him otherwise) that he was able to realize the truth, overcome the superstitions, and then face his fears / death (i.e., become something more than just a beast).

That's how it ties in with everything.

---

*P.S. "The Rules of the Beast" is also the title of the first episode.*

Answer (score 6):

Although I think it's somewhat shoddy writing, I think it's clear that

> Dracula is, at his heart, an ancient warlord who is desperate for the
>   one thing everyone else in his bloodline attained but that he can’t
>   have, which is the honor of a hero’s grave.  [1]

There is no honor, nor is there anything heroic, with entering a house uninvited.

I think this is a little bit of a stretch, trying to make age-old folklore fit into a tidy box, but clearly it's about honor and heroism.

[1] https://tv.avclub.com/dracula-s-bonkers-finale-both-keeps-it-simple-and-absur-1840834235